# python nlgserv not starting

Tags: python, jython

I tried to install and use nlgserv from
https://github.com/mnestis/nlgserv

On the first line of the code (import nlgserv) it allready brings an error:

File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\nlgserv__init__.py", line 1, in  from _controller import start_server, stop_server

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_controller'

(ps: jython is installed)

Comment: did you install it as `pip install nlgserv` ?

Comment: yes i did install nlgserv with pip bevore

Answer (score 0):

Clone the repository and install explicitly using below command. Worked for me.

```
python setup.py install
```

sometimes pip install nlgserv throws the above error.